# Why is the structure showing less memory than actual memory in the following programming

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sizeof

I wrote a program

```
include<stdio.h>
struct record
{
    int i;
    char ch[20];
};
int main()
{
    struct record a,*b;
    b=&a;
    printf("intial pointer is %p and final is %p",b++,b);
    return 0;
}
```

The size of a should be 20+4=24 but the output is

```
intial pointer is 0x7fffb0455e40 and final is 0x7fffb0455e58
```

The arithmetic is 18 bytes. Why is the output like this?

Comment: it's not 18 bytes. it's 1 * 16 + 8 = 24 bytes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reading numbers in hexadecimal.

Comment: `0x7fffb0455e58 - 0x7fffb0455e40 == 0x18`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the arithmetic is 18 bytes. why is the output like this?

Because it is hex. `0x7fffb0455e58`-`0x7fffb0455e40` is `0x18`, or 24<sub>10</sub>, which is the result that you expect.

Note that your code has undefined behavior, because `++b` and `b` are used in the same expression without a sequence point separating them. You also need to cast the value prepared for `%p` to `void*`, i.e.

```
printf("initial pointer is %p and final is %p", (void*)b, (void*)(b+1));
```